# Как сделать общую навигацию для нескольких bootsrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Можно ли чтобы несколько bootsrap corousel имели одну общую навигацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var c1 = $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel(),
      c2 = $('#carouselExampleSlidesOnly').carousel(),
      c3 = $('#carouselExampleSlidesOnly2').carousel();
  
  c1.on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
      var to = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
      c2.carousel(to);
      c3.carousel(to);
  });

});
```

```css
#controls {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-color:black!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div id="controls">
  
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carouse2">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carouse2">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```